# Why SQL where greater than is doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to select data where total greater than 3, but is not work, how to fix it?

**SQL**

```
SELECT p.image, p.id, p.name, sum(od.qty) AS total, sum(od.price * od.qty) AS nilai
FROM products p, order_details od, orders o 
WHERE  p.id = od.product_id 
AND o.id = od.order_id 
AND o.status = "Finished"
AND total > 6
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY nilai DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

**result**

[image]

Total 6 still there. Any Advice?

Comment: Because unfortunately MySQL accepts and runs malformed queries. Columns that are not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause should appear aggregated in the SELECT list (it's not the case in your example). Also, you probably want to add the predicate `total > 6` in the `HAVING` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use having group by :

```
   SELECT p.image, p.id, p.name, sum(od.qty) AS total, sum(od.price * od.qty) AS nilai
    FROM products p, order_details od, orders o 
    WHERE  p.id = od.product_id 
    AND o.id = od.order_id 
    AND o.status = "Finished" 
    GROUP BY p.id 
    HAVING sum(od.qty) > 3
    ORDER BY nilai DESC 
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: ```sum(od.qty)``` should not be part of the ```GROUP BY``` clause. That's misleading (and illegal in other RDBMS / ANSI SQL).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I think it breaks mysql as well. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4b88db73ca5acaf40b4f64b7b39b8d5